# Not able to get DB connection using CDI in JSF Managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, cdi

In my JSF managed bean (`HomePageController.java`) I am trying to obtain a DB connection using `@Resource` annotation but it remains `null` for some reason and while debugging I found that it gives `NullPointerException`.

I am using Tomcat 8 server. Could this be because Tomcat 8 is not a full featured Java EE container?

I have already define the datasource in META-INF/context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/ministore-jsf-mvc">
    <!-- PostgreSQL Datasource -->
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
              maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
              name="jdbc/ministore-db" password="postgres"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://db-server:5432/ministore-db" username="postgres"/>
</Context>
```

**web.xml snippet**

```
<!-- DB configuration (using Datasource) -->
<resource-ref>
    <description>PostgreSQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ministore-db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

**HomePageController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HomePageController implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HomePageController.class);

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/ministore-db")
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    public Product getProduct() {
        LOG.debug("Into the HomePageController...");

        //get the Product object based on productId parameter
        Product product = null;

        try {
            product = new MasterDao(dataSource).getProduct(DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID);
            LOG.debug("product = " + product);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception while getting product from DB for productId = " + DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID);
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        LOG.debug("product = " + product);
        return product;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
DEBUG com.ministore.controllers.HomePageController  - Into the HomePageController...
ERROR com.ministore.controllers.HomePageController  - Exception while getting product from DB for productId = 101
ERROR com.ministore.controllers.HomePageController  - 
DEBUG com.ministore.controllers.HomePageController  - product = null
```

Comment: As far as I know Tomcat doesn't give you any CDI support - which libraries do you include to use CDI? (I tried this once but without luck.)

Comment: I am using `javaee-web-api` library with `provided` scope in my pom. The weird part is that `@Resource` works with servlets.

Comment: Have you tried manually looking up the resource using the JNDI api? If you can get it that way, then it's the container that's screwing around. Otherwise, something's not right with your config/code

Comment: Yes, I tried manually looking up the resource using the JNDI api and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Resource(name = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/ministore-db")
```

Also remove `factory` attribute from your context file

Comment: Try to initialize it via bean constructor then uisng `InitialContext.doLookup(name:String):Object`, also have a server restart.

Comment: Also I'm not sure, but if you are in linux, the context file should be `Context.xml`(with upper C)